# Beta (Whitelisted) Email List for Registration on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm Using Devise and i'm trying to build a requirement that only emails that are included in my white list can actually Sign Up.

Over Time emails will be added to that list. Meaning that Today there are 10 emails, tomorrow another 20+.

But i don't know quite yet how to achieve this.

I know that i have to `Create my own Registrations Controller`, and for the Validation i think i need something similar to this:

```
before_validation :whitelisted?

def whitelisted?
  unless WhiteList.exists?(:email => email)
    errors.add :email, "is not on our beta list"  
  end
end
```

However, i am clueless on how to start or continue this. I don't even know if that's the best Practice.

How do i add emails to that whitelist and where is even that whitelist?

If someone could be noob-friendly enough to explain this to me.

Comment: Why not just put validation on the model? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods

Comment: The Validation is in my question. The only part i don't get is HOW to include and update those Whitelisted Emails and if this is a good practice

Comment: I think I get what you're asking now, but I suggest you make your question a little bit clearer so it's more useful for future viewers.

Comment: Do you have all whitelisted emails stored in whitelist table?

Comment: That's the point, i don't quite know how to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following i think this could help you.

create **new registration controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    unless WhiteList.exists?(:email => params[:user][:email])
      errors.add :email, "is not on our beta list"
    else
      super  
    end
  end
end
```

and in **routes file** replace existing with following

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Create new model WhiteList using following

```
rails g model whitelist email:string
```

and run `rake db:migrate` command.

after this start **Rails console** add email's using following command.

```
Whitelist.create(email: "test@user.com")
```

Comment: yeah but how can i add emails to the "WhiteList", how do i create this whitelist ?

Comment: you can create **WhiteList model** with email field and add email's through console OR you can create controller, model and view to add email's in WhiteList table with **admin** access.

Comment: Cool, could you update your Answer with that step ? the White List Model and how to add emails through the console ?

Comment: Thank you very much, so basically i can create as much emails i want through the console right ?

Comment: On another note, if you're struggling with generating and updating models, you'll be well advised to watch some railscasts and read the tutorials.

Comment: Yes you can create email's as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I found @Amit Sharma's answer useful, but it doesn't work straight out of the box. Here's what I came up with:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if WhiteList.exists?(:email => params[:user][:email].downcase)
      super
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your email is not on our beta list."
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end

class WhiteList < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :downcase_email
  validates :email, presence: true

  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end
end
```

This solves for case sensitivities when whitelisting an email and produces a flash error message when a Whitelisted email isn't matched.