# Requiring a master password for user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to Rails, my only experience thus far is completing the world-famous [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

I'm working on a separate project now, and want to restrict user registration based on a master password that would be manually provided to those I wish to register. The user would register like normal, providing their own username/password, but would also have to provide the master password to create an account. I'm having trouble translating the concepts from the tutorial into what I need, and am wondering what best-practice would be for accomplishing this.

So my questions would be:

- Should I create a new table just to store this password? I want to prevent the password from being accessible in my git repository. Do I create some kind of corresponding Model/Controller with this, or just create a table? Where do I put queries against this table?
- Currently my registration page is tied to the 'new' action in my Users controller. This master password concept isn't something stored in the User model, so would it still be part of the User controller? If not, where do I put the code that validates the password entered on the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to restrict user registrations based on a master password. I think you could simply 'white list' the users allowed to register.

All you need is a whitelist table with an email field. When a user tries to register, you validate that the email provided exists in the whitelist table and that no user is already registered with that address.

Take a look at these similar questions:

[Whitelisting with devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167576/whitelisting-with-devise)

[Beta (Whitelisted) Email List for Registration on Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131220/beta-whitelisted-email-list-for-registration-on-devise)

Good luck

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I'd hoped to avoid something like that. I'd prefer to just tell people the password when I tell them about the site, or if they call me or another admin, rather than force new users to wait for an admin to get around to whitelisting them.

Comment: Then I think you should consider using a private url that is not shown on the landing page of your app.

Comment: Something like beta.myapp.com/register that would render the registration form. It's not secured but using a 'public' password isn't either. I guess it depends on whether or not you want to accept registrations from people you don't know.

Comment: Yeah it's not meant to be the most secure thing in the world (though I don't want the password available in the html or anything silly like that). It's just meant to be a quick gatekeeper for a private community of 75-100 people. The current site (not made by me) doesn't use registration or logins, and uses the master pw as the sole means of security. I don't want that, but still don't want public registration.