# Confirm (as an admin) a User created with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise and since my app is in Beta, I want to control which users who have signed up can sign in.

So, even if the confirmation email is sent, how can I make it so that just when an admin has confirmed the account they will be able to sign in? Is there any module in Devise that would let me do so?

Comment: Take a look at this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131220/beta-whitelisted-email-list-for-registration-on-devise This is how i handled it. Not very optimal when you have A LOT of user's, but it helps out on the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add an "approved" attribute to your user table, use admin to change its status and before sign in you can check whether user is approved or not. You can find detailed information here: [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in)